# Mocha unit tests timeout error on Jenkins, but not locally

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jenkins, mocha.js

This project I'm working on has a bunch of unit tests, and the project build is being checked by Jenkins which runs those tests as well.

The problem I'm experiencing is this: Whenever I run my tests locally, no error appears. Everything works fine, whether I test the files individually or run the test on the entire project.

However, whenever I push any of my commits, Jenkins always returns this error:

```
timeout of 20000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

I'm not sure why, since it works when I test it locally and I'm sure I'm calling the done() in the tests. Also, it's always been the same two unit tests which consistently fail on Jenkins with timeouts but never locally on any of our machines.

The tests look like this:

```
it('should provide result', function(done) {
  this.timeout(20000);
  server.get(`/api/model/function/${token}`)
  .set('Authorization', access_token)
  .expect(200)
  .end((err, res) => {
    assert.equal(res.status, 200, 'expects status equal to 200');
    done(err);
  });
});
```

I've also tried rewriting it into a promise which looks like

```
it('should provide result', function(done) {
  server.get(`/api/model/function/${token}`)
  .set('Authorization', access_token)
  .then(res => {
    assert.equal(res.status, 200, 'expects status equal to 200');
    done();
  });
});
```

Which gives the same result: works fine locally but not in Jenkins.

I've looked around and saw the people suggested adding a `.catch(done)` or `.catch(err => { done(err) })` at the end, but that just results in an error `Done() called multiple times` for me.

Any help regarding this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not unusual for different "systems" to have different characteristics in terms of network connectivity etc.  Sometimes you just have to suck it up and change the timeouts for particular tests in your CI environment.  So just raise it for your failing tests like so:

```
describe("something", function () {
    this.timeout(5000);

    // tests...
});
```

However, based on what you say in the chat it sounds like the server isn't being spun up in the CI environment.  Please post the code where your server variable is set up.

Comment: I tried setting the timeout to as high as a minute (60000) and that still times out. But when I tried setting it to (60000 * 2), the error changed into `Cannot read property 'status' of undefined` which I assume is because the rest of the test already completed and is still trying to resolve that one particular test.

Comment: So you spin up the server on jekins?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I assume that's what it does.

Comment: Do you have other tests that exercise the server locally or are those the only ones?

Comment: Why don't you also post the code where that server variable is defined and set up.